# Custom ActionBarSherlock - Size & logo transparent

Tags: android, actionbarsherlock

I'm having a lot of problems in adapting a design with `ActionBarSherlock`.
And I can not find much information.
I share a couple of screenshots of the original design and the result I get.

1. How I can increase the size of ActionBarSherlock?
2. How I can add a logo centered and custom size?
3. And, why the "logo Transparent" appears with white background??

regards and thanks,

Screenshots example:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/jJNmc.png

https://i.stack.imgur.com/evb42.png

Comment: Just use a custom theme in style.xml to defined the actionbar's background?

Comment: Thanks for responding. But I do not understand how. 
I know I must modify the xml,  but I do not know what property is used to center the logo in "item"

Comment: No, just create a style in your `res/values/styles.xml` that has ActionBarSherlock as parent. Browse the web for resources (lot of them).